# Swift Auto code generation

Tags: ios, swift, auto-generate

I am new to Swift and I was working using SwagGen which generated Swift code from Swagger Style Json object. For generating code they have template files. I saw a wierd syntax for auto-generation in those files

```
public init({% if bodyParam %}_ {{ bodyParam.name}}: {{ bodyParam.optionalType }}{% if nonBodyParams %}, {% endif %}{% endif %}{% if nonBodyParams %}_ options: Options{% endif %}) {
        {% if bodyParam %}
        self.{{ bodyParam.name}} = {{ bodyParam.name}}
        {% endif %}
        {% if nonBodyParams %}
        self.options = options
        {% endif %}
        super.init(service: {{ operationId|upperCamelCase }}.service)
    }
```

What is this syntax({{% %}})? I have to make changes in this code for my personal purposes. Can any one suggest some links to learn this or explain what it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swagger uses .mustache files as template files. You should have a look at the [official documentation](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) of moustache if you don't understand its syntax.

Comment: Thank you. I will check the link provided.

Answer (score 2):

`{%%}` <- is for controlling stuff, like

`{% if %}`

`{% else %}`

`{% endif %}`

`{{}}` <- is for printing something, like

`{{ my_variable }}` or `{{ my_object.attribute }}`